# Uploadify not working with PHP 5.5

Tags: php, uploadify

We recently upgraded php from 5.3 to 5.5.  All seems to have gone well, except uploadify (HTML5) no longer works when trying to upload batch images.

I checked their site for help and it looks like the last update was April 23, 2012.  http://www.uploadify.com/download/download-uploadifive-standard/

Not really sure what we can do.  Is anyone familiar with this and have a solution?

Comment: They don't seem to support the script anymore either..  I can't find any contact info and the forum is locked down.

Comment: have you checked the error logs? make sure error_reporting(E_ALL);  ~